# Programmatically filtering contacts in Outlook 2010 Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, filtering, contacts

I am trying to programmatically filter Outlook contacts in the Contacts folder in Outlook 2010. I followed DASL filter rules, but it seems working for `Find` function and throws exception when I assign this filter to `view.Filter = FilterString`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? The correct result would display filtered contacts in the existing contacts view.

```
Outlook.Application myApp = ThisAddIn.myApp; 
Outlook.NameSpace myNamespace = ThisAddIn.nSpace; 
Outlook.MAPIFolder myContactsFolder = ThisAddIn.contactsFolder;
if (myContactsFolder == null)
{
    Log.Verbose("Contacts folder not found");
    return null;
}

Outlook.Items contactItems = ThisAddIn.contactItems; 

//use filter to take only contact and not DistListItem  
Outlook.Items outlookContacts = contactItems.Restrict("[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Contact'");
Outlook.ContactItem contact = null;

int iOutlookContacts = contactItems.Count;
if (iOutlookContacts > 0)
{
    string FilterString = "[FullName]='" + param + "'"; 

    // Find works with this filter
    contact = (Outlook.ContactItem)outlookContacts.Find(FilterString); 
    if (contact != null)
    {
        // need to display in contacts search window
        Outlook.View currentView = myApp.ActiveExplorer().CurrentView;
        currentView.Filter = FilterString; // cannot parse exception occurs here

        currentView.Save();
        currentView.Apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add your specific error message, i.e.: `Cannot parse condition. Error at "[FullName]='...'".`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your DASL search filter to this:

```cs
string FilterString = "\"urn:schemas:contacts:cn\"='" + param + "'";
```

`[FullName]` is not a valid search filter column. The **Full Name** field [maps to the DASL search column `urn:schemas:contacts:cn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ms873094%28v=exchg.65%29)

Comment: Thank you! That worked well, except that I need to eliminate currentView.Save() statement - otherwise all my contacts get eliminated from Outlook...

Comment: Also, how do I combine conditions, that is, for example, finding if the param variable matches either last name or first name and the company matches variable param1 ?

Comment: A strange thing that I observed through is that Outlook complains that Instant Search is not available when user runs with Admin privileges... so it keeps showing marquee progress without displaying any filtered results...

Comment: @LeonHavin Please post your subsequent questions in a new post. [SO is not a discussion forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/171414), it is a [Q & A site](http://stackoverflow.com/about).